# Certificate errors even when I import the CA certificate to the store

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I'm troubleshooting a Windows 10 machine access to a server with a certificate signed by a CA that isn't in the default Windows certificate store.

The site https://www.eprotocolo.pr.gov.br/ is using a certificate signed by the Brazilian Government CA ICP-Brasil with the following chain:

```
-> Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5
--> AC Certisign G7
---> AC Certisign Multipla SSL
----> www.eprotocolo.pr.gov.br
```

From the ICP-Brasil website, I can download the root certificate and all the intermediate CAs certificates. With those files in hand, I am now trying to fix the problem.

Trying to access the site in Chrome from **Linux** I get `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. To solve the problem I went to **Settings -> Certificates -> Authorities -> Import** and selected the "AC Certisign Multipla SSL" certificate and checked the option "Thrust this certificate to identify websites". Now, trying to access the site it works perfectly.

In Chrome from **Windows** I get the `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID` error. Following the same approach that I used on Linux, I tried the following without success:

- Importing the "AC Certisign Multipla SSL" to the Windows store using Chrome dialog inside settings.
- Importing the "AC Certisign Multipla SSL" by double-clicking it in the Explorer.
- Importing the "AC Certisign Multipla SSL" to the Windows store using `certmgr.msc` snap-in. I also repeated this step multiple times, importing the cert to the multiple stores available (root, intermediate, third party) and physical stores (Local Computer/Registry).
- Importing all the certificates in the chain to the stores.
- I prepared a Virtual Machine with a clean installation of Windows 10 to rule out any interference from other software or settings and tested all the steps again.

Now I'm stuck and don't know what to do next, maybe I'm missing something about the different error that I'm getting on Windows.

**UPDATE 1:**
Following the instructions in the comments I re-imported the certificates to the Local Machine storage (`certlm.msc` instead of `certmgr.msc`). I took some screenshots to be sure I'm doing everything right, this link contains the [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPvOI.jpg) of the error and the store before and after the imports. I rebooted the machine to be sure the certs would persist in the store and the new configurations would be applied, they are still there but the error persists.

Obs.: I can't post images due to my reputation, for this reason I posted them as a link.

Comment: You can't import CAs or ICAs through a web browser, as both require admin privileges (something a web browser should _never_ have).  Download the certs, right-click each > select Import > Local Machine > manually choose the certificate store for each.  CAs need to be imported into the Trusted Root Certificate Authority store, while ICAs need to be imported into the Intermediate Certificate Authority store.  Once done, the issue should be resolved if that was the only issue.

Comment: The reason your getting these errors is something is right about those certificates.  Even if you trust those certificates the browser might still consider the secure connection inadequate and unsafe based on the certificate and warn you

Comment: @JW0914 I did that without success. Both from the right-click->import and from the certmgr. The account I'm using is an Administrator Account and all the certs appears in the right store after importing, but It didn't worked.

Comment: Then, as @Ramhound mentioned, something regarding the certificate likely isn't right.  You can try completely closing out Chrome then re-openning as well as using `openssl` to verify the cert and ICAs _(you did import both ICAs into the ICA store right)_..  Most often it's due to lazy certificate issuers allowing non-allowed options within the Common Name, such as the IP and hostname, both of which should not be specified in the CN, but within the SAN _(listing them in the CN is a security issue)_.

Comment: Windows already includes the required root-CA certificate on Windows. You don't have to add anything. The problem is located elsewhere. [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.eprotocolo.pr.gov.br&latest) reports an OCSP error when checking the certificate. May be this has an impact on the Windows version of Chrome? Also the certificate is not covered by "Certificate Transparency" which is AFAIK a requirement since April 2018.

Comment: @Robert You have the CA and ICAs listed in the OP's question within your certificate store _(I don't)_?  What root-CA are you referring to?

Comment: @JW0914 Latest Windows 10. Root CA is `Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5`. The ICAs are part of the Server Hello. I never added this CA cert manually. The SSLLabs report also states that the cert is trusted on Windows.

Comment: As pointed by you guys, maybe the problem really is in the certificate, hence the ERR_CERT_INVALID and not the ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. So I'm trying to solve it in the wrong place. Is there anything I can do to tell windows that it can trust this cert?

Comment: @Paschoal `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` is exactly what it says, an issue in the chain of trust or a cert is self-signed.  All three certificate authorities must be installed into the correct certificate stores (CA to the Root CA store, ICAs to the ICA store). When you imported, did you select Local Machine and _not_ Current User?  Use `openssl` directly to verify each certificate, starting with the CA, then moving on to each ICA, and finally the server's certificate.

Comment: @Robert That CA, nor the two ICAs, are not a default Windows installed CA or ICA... it may be on a Portuguese language install or a PC sold in Brazil, perhaps by installing a specific piece of software or Windows feature, but it's never been a default CA or ICA installed on any Windows PC I've used, all of which are running v1909. `CertMgr.msc` [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/7X6elos)

Comment: @ JW0914 The Root-CA "Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5" was added by Microsoft 2019-03-26. See the official root-CA list by Microsoft: 
 https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Trusted-Root-Program-86901ff5 (see row 42)

Comment: @JW0914 Yes, but I **don't** get this error in windows, I get the CERT_INVALID. I'll try to re-import everything again to be sure I'm putting each cert in the right place, although I'm pretty sure I selected Local Machine every time. Thank you for your tips.

Comment: @Paschoal I misread your prior comment, my bad =]

Comment: @JW0914 That is interesting. I checked a second Windows 1909 Machine. This machine does not have the root-CA installed. But once I open the page in Chrome it is automatically added. Looks like the untrusted root error triggers a lookup at Microsoft and enforces that the CA is automatically added.

Comment: The certificate displayed a SSL error (untrusted certificate) on my iOS device and all my Windows machines.  There is something incorrect about the certificate, as I said, even if you trust the certificate browsers will complain about the certificate unless it's fixed.  There is no client side fix other then using a different version of Chrome with relax requirements